# How to fix wrong rotation of photo from camera in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-camera

I'm taking a photo with the newest camera plugin version and I'm using code from flutter example. This is how I pick a camera:

```
final cameras = await availableCameras();
final firstCamera = cameras.first;
```

This is inside init:

```
_cameraController = CameraController(
  widget.camera,
  ResolutionPreset.medium,
  enableAudio: false,
);
```

This is the rest of the relevant code:

```
Future _takePhoto(BuildContext context) async {
  try {
    await _initializeControllerFuture;
    final path = join(
      (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
      '${DateTime.now()}.png',
    );

    await _cameraController.takePicture(path);

    setState(() {
      _imagePath = path;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Afterwards, I show the photo to the user with `Image.file(File(_imagePath))` and later I send the photo to API.
The problem is that the photo is sometimes captured with a wrong orientation. (I'm sure about this because the photo is also rotated in the database.) For example, on 3 years old Xiaomi phone, it works flawlessly, but on a certain new Samsung phone, the photo is always rotated.

How to make sure that the rotation is always correct? (Even on ios devices)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_exif_rotation 
Support `iOS` and `Android` 
In some devices the exif data shows picture in landscape mode when they're actually in portrait.
This plugin fixes the orientation for pictures taken with those devices.

For Android 
Add this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

code snippet

```
image = await FlutterExifRotation.rotateImage(path: image.path);

//Note : iOS not implemented
image = await FlutterExifRotation.rotateAndSaveImage(path: image.path);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how would I use the rotateImage function if I want to overwrite the original image?

Comment: image = await FlutterExifRotation.rotateAndSaveImage(path: image.path); but iOS not support.

Comment: Is there any solution for ios? For my specific case, I would only need to always set the image to portrait.

Comment: File image = await FlutterExifRotation.rotateImage(path: path); Doesn't work. The async function never returns anything

Comment: could you try example code Future getImageAndSave() async {
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null && image.path != null) {

      // Note : iOS not implemented
      image = await FlutterExifRotation.rotateAndSaveImage(path: image.path);

      if (image != null) {
        setState(() {
          _image = image;
        });
      }
    }
  }

Comment: Your function above worked (instead of changing state inside the function I returned the image and then setState with image.path) File image = await getImageAndSave();

Comment: Future fixExif(String path) async {
    File image = File(path);
    image = await FlutterExifRotation.rotateImage(path: image.path);
    return image;
  } 
This code ran on my phone. I'll test it on the problematic device today. Will it work on ios though?

Comment: according to package's description. FlutterExifRotation.rotateImage also work on iOS.

Comment: Just tried it on the problematic device and it's still rotating the photo.

Comment: I suggest post an issue to allow package owner check it.

Answer (score 45):

This worked for me:

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

...

final img.Image capturedImage = img.decodeImage(await File(path).readAsBytes());
final img.Image orientedImage = img.bakeOrientation(capturedImage);
await File(path).writeAsBytes(img.encodeJpg(orientedImage));
```

Comment: simple and effective

Comment: this comment helped me so much! THANKS!

Comment: This saved the day! Thanks for this

Comment: This worked out good for me as I was already using the image plugin, thanks! Too bad the already slow capturing of an image gets even slower and worse why is such a severe bug still live in flutter after 2+ years

Comment: This is the simplest solution which just worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir!

Comment: you saved me a lot! thank you, and alsı, we can do same operation process without file; like;  final XFile image=await cameraController!.takePicture();
    img.Image? capturedImage=img.decodeImage(await image.readAsBytes());
    capturedImage=img.copyRotate(capturedImage!, 90);
    takenImage=Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(capturedImage));

Comment: Up until dec 2021, using the latest update of camera plugin, the orientation bug still exists (on Samsung A10 phone). This solution by Mark Laughton simply works!. Thanks.!

Comment: I have a problem:
Image size increases n times after Rotating

Answer (score 13):

This is my solution that works cross-platform and doesn't use plugins.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:exif/exif.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

Future<File> fixExifRotation(String imagePath) async {
    final originalFile = File(imagePath);
    List<int> imageBytes = await originalFile.readAsBytes();

    final originalImage = img.decodeImage(imageBytes);

    final height = originalImage.height;
    final width = originalImage.width;

    // Let's check for the image size
    // This will be true also for upside-down photos but it's ok for me
    if (height >= width) {
      // I'm interested in portrait photos so
      // I'll just return here
      return originalFile;
    }

    // We'll use the exif package to read exif data
    // This is map of several exif properties
    // Let's check 'Image Orientation'
    final exifData = await readExifFromBytes(imageBytes);

    img.Image fixedImage;

    if (height < width) {
      logger.logInfo('Rotating image necessary');
      // rotate
      if (exifData['Image Orientation'].printable.contains('Horizontal')) {
        fixedImage = img.copyRotate(originalImage, 90);
      } else if (exifData['Image Orientation'].printable.contains('180')) {
        fixedImage = img.copyRotate(originalImage, -90);
      } else if (exifData['Image Orientation'].printable.contains('CCW')) {
        fixedImage = img.copyRotate(originalImage, 180);
      } else {
        fixedImage = img.copyRotate(originalImage, 0);
      }
    }

    // Here you can select whether you'd like to save it as png
    // or jpg with some compression
    // I choose jpg with 100% quality
    final fixedFile =
        await originalFile.writeAsBytes(img.encodeJpg(fixedImage));

    return fixedFile;
  }
```

[Source](https://roszkowski.dev/2020/rotate-image-from-camera-in-flutter/)

Comment: to use this code. add await to make your function accept Future<File>:     File file2 = await fixExifRotation(imageFile.path);

Comment: if (height == width) {
      print('height == width');
      fixedImage = img.copyRotate(originalImage, 90);
      return await originalFile.writeAsBytes(img.encodeJpg(fixedImage));

Comment: image_picker: ^0.6.6+1
  exif: ^1.0.2
  image: ^2.1.12

Comment: @Russo Did you get this working?  I am using an iPad Mini 2, and when taking a photo in portrait if falls into the bottom else{} condition and does not rotation the image.  If you have it working would you please be able to publish a working example

Comment: @Dominik I dont think the if condition is exhaustive.  I printed out the exifData['Image Orientation'].printable and it is returning '90 CW' for me.  I think this also needs to be considered in the If statement.  For reference, i am testing on an iPad Mini 2.

Comment: Thanks @teh_raab for clarification!

Comment: @teh_raab after taking the photo, it was rotated, but then after clicking on "confirm photo", then it becomes correctly oriented.

Comment: [A post on the exiftool forum](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=7909.0)  provides a full list of all the orientation values:
1 = Horizontal (normal)
2 = Mirror horizontal
3 = Rotate 180
4 = Mirror vertical
5 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 270 CW
6 = Rotate 90 CW
7 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 90 CW
8 = Rotate 270 CW

Comment: This an acceptable solution @DominikRoszkowski but ideally just the exif orientation metadata should be corrected and written out instead of actually modifying the rotation of the underlying image data which will not be a necessarily a lossless operation.

Comment: Hi Dominik, this solution is fantastic. However, I'm wondering why this same method can't be used to rotate a file that's already been selected? e.g. I use ImagePicker and rotate with this method, then I try to rotate my new file with a similar method but it doesn't work .. Please check you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64498774/how-to-rotate-a-selected-set-image-flutter

Comment: This doesn't work for me and also the exif and image are both external plugins. Cannot say this solution doesn't use plugins. :)

Comment: This solution worked for me, while `bakeOrientation` didn't.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this package [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress) to resolve the camera image orientation problem. Note that this approach is faster than using the **image** package approach.

Use it this way:

```
import 'package:flutter_image_compress/flutter_image_compress.dart';

........

final fixedImageBytes = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile(
  image.path,
  rotate: 0,
  quality: 100,
  keepExif: false,
  autoCorrectionAngle: true,
  format: CompressFormat.jpeg,
);
```

Note:
Make sure to set **autoCorrectionAngle** to *true*, **keepExif** to *false* and **rotate** to *0*

Comment: notice this package does not support web

Answer (score 3):

if you want to rotate image, you can use  **https://pub.dev/packages/image**  to manipulate images:

```
import 'package:image/image.dart';
```

If you use package "camera", you can't rotate image (remove mirror effect) using bakeOrientation because don't have exif data.

this works for me using "image_picker" or "camera".

```
File originalFile             = File.fromUri(Uri(path: file.path));
List<int> imageBytes           = await originalFile.readAsBytes();
final Image originalImage      = decodeImage(imageBytes)!;
final Image orientedImage      = flipHorizontal(originalImage);
List<int> imageBytesOrientated = encodeJpg(orientedImage);
```

For Write in same path:

```
await File(path).writeAsBytes(imageBytesOrientated);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I just wanna to share how I fix my issue, you can call this function after it's initialized or every time before you take a photo, and here is the code:

```
await _camCtrl.lockCaptureOrientation(DeviceOrientation.portraitUp);
```

This fix my issue, somebody says it won't work on iOS, but I haven't test that it, so you can test it out and see if it is compatible with iOS or not.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party. It is really bad idea to ask Flutter to rotate images or similar operations because mobile apps are not designed for these purposes. The only reasonable use case is to ask Flutter to resize the image because you don't want to send a high resolution image to your server over the mobile connection. My solution is send your full size (if you prefer and resize in the back end) or resized images from Flutter to the back end where you can do auto orientation. I use MagickNET lib which is cross platform to do the job and it works perfectly. By doing this, your Flutter code is much cleaner and tidier.

Answer (score 0):

***--- VERY SIMPLE SOLUTION ---***

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

XFile xfile = await _cameraController.takePicture();

List<int> imageBytes = await xfile.readAsBytes();

img.Image? originalImage = img.decodeImage(imageBytes);
img.Image fixedImage = img.flipVertical(originalImage!);

File file = File(xfile.path);

File fixedFile = await file.writeAsBytes(
  img.encodeJpg(fixedImage),
  flush: true,
);
```

Comment: this rotates every image by 180 degree..

Comment: this is the example. you can use img.flipHorizantal function to flip to other side which you needed.

Comment: it is not for rotating its for flipping image. I had problem with front camera returning images flipped. This helped me a lot thanks