# ML Vision Text is not working in portrait

Tags: firebase, flutter, exif, firebase-mlkit, mlvision

I am having an issue with Flutter firebase_ml_vision.  When testing on an iPad Mini 2 (seen this on android in the past), no text is detected when taking the photo in Portrait. It seems to work in landscape.  I had the exact same issue when i was writing the original app in Native Android (i since decided to make it in Flutter/Dart)

I have spent a few hours now trying to figure this out.  This seems to be a known issue but with no general consensus on the solution.

The closest i got to it working was with [This SO fixExifRotation() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176001/how-to-fix-wrong-rotation-of-photo-from-camera-in-flutter) however the text that is read is scrambled.

Has anyone come across this issue and found a working solution?

```
Future<String> takePicture() async {
  File imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.camera,
    imageQuality: 100,
  );

  if (imageFile == null) {
    return null;
  }

  final appDir = await syspaths.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final fileName = path.basename(rotatedFile.path);

  final savedImage = await rotatedFile.copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');
  return '${appDir.path}/$fileName';
}

...
Future<MLResult> processText({@required BuildContext context,String imageFilePath}) async {
  final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage =
      FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(imageFilePath);
  final TextRecognizer _recognizer = FirebaseVision.instance.textRecognizer();
  final VisionText readText = await _recognizer.processImage(visionImage);

  var blocks = readText.blocks;
  if (blocks.length == 0) {
    //*** THIS IF BLOCK IS EXECUTED - no text is detected by ML Vision.
  }
}

imagePath = await Vision.takePicture();
Vision.processText(
    context: context,
    imageFilePath: imagePath,
  ).then((value) {..});
```